# PHP : array not retaining value

Tags: php, arrays

The goal of this snip-it was to loop an array of of arrays describing resources.
Then looping an array of caption information. If they match add that caption to this `resource_node` index.

The first `echo print_r($resource);` has the 'caption' index key.

The second `echo print_r($this->resource_nodes);` does not show the caption keys.

I have no idea what is going wrong in this snip-it.

```
foreach ($this->resource_nodes as $resource) {
    foreach ($this->captions as $caption) {
        if ($resource['attachment id'] === $caption['id']) {
            $resource['caption'] = $caption['content'];
            echo print_r($resource);
        }
    }
}
echo print_r($this->resource_nodes);
```

The comparison `echo` works. So I know that the captions are assigned to some array, and that the arrays are identical except for the missing caption after loop execution.

Any idea what is causing this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your $resource variable is being set by value, not by reference. Try:

```
foreach ($this->resource_nodes as &$resource) {
```

Note the '&'.

Comment: Thank you so much. I had forgotten about explicit reference.